# How can I distribute traffic web requests geographically?

Tags: web-hosting, geolocation

If I have two web frontends. one in Dallas, one in London. How can I best route traffic from the US to Dallas, and abroad to London?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother, just use a CDN that routes your static requests geographically, and serve up your actual website (the .index.php for instance) at which ever location you wish.

You could use a load balancer for redundancy but I don't think that you need to pay that much attention to the actual location of the server script. It is the web resources and static assets where you need to geo-serve which can be done by any CDN such as CloudFront on Amazon.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/